# I could not understand "to look for with reason or justification" in the definition of "expect"

Tags: meaning

I got some text that I can not understand when I checked the meaning of "expect" from the dictionary.

From [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/expect):

> to look for with reason or justification:
>     *We expect obedience.*

I suppose "look for" means "search for" here, but I can't guess out the means of "with" here.

I found some common words, like *as*, *to*, *with*, *in* or *by*, are very hard to understand due to too many meanings they have.

Comment: Welcome:  Did you write the text? Did you read it somewhere? What is the connection between looking for something and expecting obedience? Please name your source and, if possible give a link to the original.  We cannot improve your text if we do not know what you are trying to say. Please give context. Thanks.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK thanks for view my question. I edited my text and add the source link  to the question.

Comment: "look for" is idiomatic, meaning roughly  "look forward to" or "anticipate". That is, to wait for something that you believe will happen.  http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/look+for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

!@#$%^&*(

The definition and the phrase really don't support each other well. You're right that "to look for" typically means search. For example "I need *to look for* my keys."

In English "to look for" also has an idiomatic meaning of having a strong belief in something. So an army drill instructor would say to the recruits "We expect obedience."  The instructor is telling the recruits that there is no doubt in his mind that the army's orders are to be followed.